# How to take a backup of an SSD AWS [ec2]?

Tags: amazon-ec2, backup, recovery, solid-state-drive

I have an `m3 large`. Although I can find the other EBS volumes associated with that instance in the *Volumes* Section.

But I am not able to find my 32GB SSD disk.

How can we take backup of this SSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are referring to the **Instance Store SSD volume** that is provided as part of an `m3.large` Amazon EC2 instance.

**Instance Store** volumes are temporary (aka "[ephemeral](http://dilbert.com/strip/2013-06-05)") and the content is lost when the instance is Stopped, Terminated or fails. Therefore, it is recommended only for temporary files and swap files. Be sure to copy off any data you wish to keep before the instance is Stopped.

Instance Store volumes are **not the same as Elastic Block Store (EBS) volumes**. While EBS provides a **snapshot** capability, this is **not available** for Instance Store volumes.

Instead, you must copy off any data you wish to keep via **normal filesystem commands**, or run **traditional backup software**. There is no snapshot-like capability available for Instance Store volumes.

Comment: So if the instance is like an m5d.2xlarge with 2x300GB SSD, and for some reason the instance is restarted or need to be migrated / relocated - this can rarely happen -, the 600 GB data is *pooof gone*? That would be shocking because for example I'd install the OS there (it's speedier than EBS). So suddenly I'd have a box with no OS or nothing if the instance is brought down and back up???

Comment: @CsabaToth Restarting does not affect Instance Store, since a restart only affects the OS, but the virtual machine remains unchanged. However, stopping an instance removes the VM, so the contents would be gone. If the OS is on instance store, it would not successfully Start after a Stop. Therefore, only use Instance Store for temporary data, or content that can be reloaded from elsewhere. (In the old days, before Amazon EBS, it wasn't even possible to stop/start, since all storage was Instance Store.)